# Galaxy s5 adoptable storage

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, adoptable-storage

So I am trying to make my galaxy s5 take my new sd card as internal. I Followed the instructions from [Unable to adopt SD card as internal storage using Marshmallow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/unable-to-adopt-sd-card-as-internal-storage-using-marshmallow?newreg=88b4b0d7c8654f068e598f9e9c912232). But I can't comment to ask about my error (Too New here) so I made a new question.

Every time I get the partition part I get this [image: Command Prompt Screen Shot]

The SD card is a 128gb 90MB/s SanDisk Extreme.

Samsung-SM-G900A, (AT&T btw) running 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the full line returned from the sm list-disks command.
disk:179,64

Therefore the command to partition the SD card would be:

```
sm partition disk:179,64 private
```

You dropped the `disk:`  from the command shown in your screen shot.

If you get a timeout error, then try reformatting the SD card.

Comment: Sweet, It worked. I don't think I would have spotted such a obvious mistake.