# Samsung J5 : Use SD card as internal memory

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, internal-sd, adoptable-storage, samsung-galaxy-j5

I'm actually trying to use my SD card as internal memory on my Samsung Galaxy J5 with 6.0.1 android version.
I saw some post on google and i follow this tutotial :

http://www.phonandroid.com/galaxy-s7-s7-edge-fusionner-memoire-interne-carte-sd-sans-root.html (It's in french because i'm french)

but when i try to use sm partition in adb shell nothing is happening... and my internal memory still the same.
As you can see on the tutorial other people got the same bug on Samsung J5.

If someone have a solution or a way to solve it.

Comment: Did you try this? http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j5/how-to/finally-adoptable-storage-j500fmm-t3470225

Comment: See our `adoptable-storage` tag for more information, especially the [questions in the tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info).

Comment: @beeshyams No i didn't find this forum, i will try it as soon as possible. I will check the tag if it doesn't work. Thanks you.

Comment: Welcom. You can post a reply to your own question to help others. It's encouraged

Comment: I tryed to use this method but i need to root my phone and i don't very like this... do you know if it's safe to do this on J5 ?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not familiar with this device. Please search in XDA

Answer (score 8):

This is how I achieved this on a Samsung Galaxy J5 with Marshmallow 6.0.1.
It requires a computer running Windows vista/7/8/10:

1. Install the official Samsung drivers on your computer - some other driver variants can cause this process not to work: http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows
2. Install Odin on your computer: https://odindownload.com/download/
3. [Enable Developer Options](https://wccftech.com/enable-developer-options-in-android-6-marshmallow) on your phone.
4. In settings->Developer Options, turn on 'Oem Unlock' and 'USB Debugging'.
5. Download this zip package: https://download.chainfire.eu/1021/SuperSU/SR3-SuperSU-v2.79-SR3-20170114223742.zip -- and save it to a known location on your phone eg. downloads.
6. Install TWRP -- this particular one -- others do not work on Marshmallow: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j5/development/recovery-samsung-galaxy-j500f-t3416960 
   . Follow the instructions on the page to install, however be aware that for this to work, the *First Time* the phone resets after the flashing process, you must hold <kbd>Vol Up</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> +  <kbd>Power key</kbd> to boot into TWRP. The timing on this is reasonably quick, so keep an eye and your hands on your phone during the flashing process. If you don't do it the first time, you will need to repeat this step, as on subsequent reboots you will not be able to get it to boot into TWRP if you didn't do it the first time.
7. Now download and install Root Essentials from Google Play Store. Run it, go to Adoptable Storage and follow the instructions. Root Essentials will ask you to download a specific zip package (do so). Then go through the process again, and follow the prompts to reboot into TWRP mode and install the package from the Install menu. Once you've done this, and the phone reboots (it will reboot loop several times, don't worry) it should boot up properly, and may go through an 'App optimizing' process.
8. Once booted, you should go into settings->storage, and you should see that your overall storage has increased. Click on the SD card, click on the '...' button in the top left and click on 'Migrate Data'. This should move existing app data (that can be moved) and photos/music to the SD card, and change the default photo storage location to the SD card.
9. Lastly, go into settings->Apps->Application Manager. Some existing Apps can be moved entirely to the SD card eg. messenger. To do so, click on the app, then storage. If an option to move it is available for that App, the 'Change' button should be available. Click on it and follow the process.

Voila! Enjoy!

Do not mess with adb's, Link2SD's or anything else -- I have wasted too much time on those before I figured out a way that works!

Comment: And very important: **Enable usb debugging** and **activate OEM unlock** (and leave it activated after rooting etc., otherwise you will get a «Custom binary blocked by FRP» screen when restarting your phone) on your phone. Without that it wont work neither with Windows, nor with Linux or anything else and you will search the internet for solutions for ever. Took me two days.

Comment: For me this solution **worked, but only with Odin version 3.10.6** which was included in the zip-package at [https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/). And it is very important to read and follow the instructions included in *Root Essentials* when doing the transition to adoptable storage (hint: do not forget to *migrate your data*, because if you forget that, your new installed Apps will still reside on the internal memory).

Comment: The most recent Odin version worked fine for me.

Comment: after pointing to storage sd card , there is no migrate. but internal memory has this option!whats wrong?

Comment: @Pasha Followed your instructions, stuck at #7 - even after installing "ASPlugin.zip" through TWRP, the Root Essentials app again prompts to install ASPlugin.zip. Am I missing anything ??

Answer (score 0):

Work on Samsung J5 SM 500G
From Official marshmallow
Install TWRP with Odin ( TWRP_J500G_MM)
Root using [6.0] UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.76 volume up+home+power
Install Root Essential
Storage - Adoptable storage - adopt
Turn off
Enter TWRP
Install ASPlugin
Root Essential
Storage - Adoptable storage - adopt - reboot
Setting - storage - sd card - migrate data - export
Finish

Answer (score -1):

Another easy way is there.
I tried it on my J5 with success:

First you need to root the device and install [Root Essentials](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superthomaslab.rootessentials&hl=en) from the Play Store. 
Follow the instructions on the screen (you need to use a very good SD class 10 with high write speed).

Comment: This answer could be helpful if you **link to the app** you're recommending, and describe **what** instructions you followed.

Answer (score -1):

You should root your phone first,
use a class 10 memory card and re partition your SDcard in ext4 file system. Then you can use some application to make it as internal memory. I found some custom OS like cyanogenmod has this feature already. Do it at your own risk

Comment: Why would he should root phone if he wants to use adoptable storage..

Comment: because The adoptable storage feature of MM encrypts the SD card. But using the apps like Link2SD didn't encrypts the SD card and you can also use the other partition(FAT32) as your media storage.

Comment: You can have a partition for media with adoptable storage. But encryption on partition for apps still stay. Not a big deal