# does ATT ZTE Z831 Android disable the internal storage option

Tags: att

My son just got the  ATT ZTE Z831 Android and I am putting in a 32GB sd card. I was wondering if this phone has an internal storage option.

Answer (score 0):

not by design. see [SuperThomasLab's answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/unable-to-adopt-sd-card-as-internal-storage-using-marshmallow) (sm partition disk...) to trick it. "mixed 50" corrupted my card (YMMV), but assigning the whole card to internal seems to have worked for me. open the card when you're done and tap "migrate data." card will no longer work as a portable (unless you reformat it as such).[image: SD card still present, but can no longer change "save location"]