# ZTE n817 android

Tags: factory-reset

[does ATT ZTE Z831 Android disable the internal storage option](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164781/does-att-zte-z831-android-disable-the-internal-storage-option)

My ZTE n817 is stuck on the screen FTM i took out the battery and when i turned it back on it still said FTM what do i do because i want to factory reset it but it wont let me and nothing is fixing it

Comment: Why did you link to this other question? Is it related in some way?

Answer (score 0):

To get into recovery mode:

1. Power off the device.
2. Then press the power & volume up keys at
   the same time.
3. Hold down until the Android appears, release.

Note step 2: Pressing the volume key down instead up takes you to Factory Test Mode (FTM).