# Linux Deploy ext4 and Adoptable Storage

Tags: linux, adoptable-storage, ext4

**Edit:**

I created [an issue](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/issues/820) in the Linux Deploy project.

---

I have a smartphone with the following settings:

[image]

And the following SD:

[image]

Ok, it's not a good SD, but that's what I have for today...

I was using SD as an extension to internal storage, and I was able to store applications and files there normally.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I would like to use [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) through [Linux Deploy](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy) (if there is no other way), but the system can only have a [maximum of 4GB](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/issues/395#issuecomment-177475166) per account of the created *.img* file and the format of the card, which is very little in my opinion.

So I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy/wiki/Installing-Kali-Linux-Guide) for an installation with more space for the operating system.

I created a three partitions:

- Fat32 to continue using on my smartphone as before (with less space of course);
- An additional swap...
- And an ext4 for the operating system installation.

[image]
[image]

I've ejected the ext4 partition to install Kali Linux. And everything worked perfectly!

Well... Almost everything!

Kali Linux was working just the way I wanted it, but when I tried to use my smartphone as before, I realized that I could no longer transfer my applications to the fat32 partition I created for it.

[image]

The option to transfer applications to SD is no longer displayed.

I tried to transform part of SD as Adoptable Storage again but do it directly from the smartphone, formatting all the storage, undoing all created partitions.

I then followed [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/146529/228277) (both with `adb`, and with [Root Essentials](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superthomaslab.rootessentials)). Which again undid my partitions. But I re-did it again following the following steps:

1. Format everything and use 50% for Adoptable Storage (by `adb` or Root Essentials).
2. Remove the SD from the smartphone and insert it into the computer to create the other partitions (ext4) with [MiniTool](http://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html) because [Android Partition Tool (AParted)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted) was not able to do this.

[image]

Ok, now I can transfer my applications to SD, and I also have the ext4 partition for installing Kali Linux, but now Linux Deploy can not see this partition mounted or ejected by Android.

**Monted:**

[image]

```
[12:36:31] >>> status
[12:36:32] Device: MotoG3
[12:36:32] Android: 7.1.2
[12:36:32] Architecture: armv7l
[12:36:32] Kernel: 3.10.49-MPI24.241-2.35-1-g4023d70
[12:36:32] Memory: 38/898 MB
[12:36:32] Swap: 273/511 MB
[12:36:32] SELinux: yes
[12:36:32] Loop devices: yes
[12:36:32] Support binfmt_misc: no
[12:36:32] Supported FS: ext2 ext3 ext4 f2fs fuseblk vfat 
[12:36:32] Installed system: unknown
[12:36:32] Status of components: 
[12:36:32] :: extra/dbus ... stopped
[12:36:32] :: extra/ssh ... stopped
[12:36:32] :: graphics/vnc ... stopped
[12:36:32] Mounted parts: 
[12:36:32]  ...nothing mounted
[12:36:32] Available mount points: 
[12:36:33] * /system  0.9/2.2 GB (ext4)
[12:36:33] * /data  4.5/11.8 GB (f2fs)
[12:36:33] * /cache  0.2/0.2 GB (ext4)
[12:36:33] * /fsg  0.0/0.0 GB (ext4)
[12:36:33] * /firmware  0.0/0.0 GB (ext4)
[12:36:33] * /persist  0.0/0.0 GB (ext4)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/runtime/default/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /storage/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/runtime/read/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/runtime/write/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/media_rw/f86f8583-23fb-d201-f063-858323fbd201  13.0/13.7 GB (ext4)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/runtime/default/f86f8583-23fb-d201-f063-858323fbd201  13.0/13.7 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /storage/f86f8583-23fb-d201-f063-858323fbd201  13.0/13.7 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/runtime/read/f86f8583-23fb-d201-f063-858323fbd201  13.0/13.7 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/runtime/write/f86f8583-23fb-d201-f063-858323fbd201  13.0/13.7 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:36:33] * /mnt/expand/bd43c04c-2500-40bd-9325-1de5ae577eb6  14.2/14.8 GB (f2fs)
[12:36:33] Available partitions: 
[12:36:34]  ...no available partitions
[12:36:34] <<< status
```

**Ejected:**

```
[12:39:49] >>> status
[12:39:49] Device: MotoG3
[12:39:49] Android: 7.1.2
[12:39:49] Architecture: armv7l
[12:39:49] Kernel: 3.10.49-MPI24.241-2.35-1-g4023d70
[12:39:49] Memory: 42/898 MB
[12:39:49] Swap: 216/511 MB
[12:39:49] SELinux: yes
[12:39:49] Loop devices: yes
[12:39:49] Support binfmt_misc: no
[12:39:49] Supported FS: ext2 ext3 ext4 f2fs fuseblk vfat 
[12:39:49] Installed system: unknown
[12:39:49] Status of components: 
[12:39:49] :: extra/dbus ... stopped
[12:39:49] :: extra/ssh ... stopped
[12:39:49] :: graphics/vnc ... stopped
[12:39:49] Mounted parts: 
[12:39:49]  ...nothing mounted
[12:39:49] Available mount points: 
[12:39:49] * /system  0.9/2.2 GB (ext4)
[12:39:49] * /data  4.5/11.8 GB (f2fs)
[12:39:50] * /cache  0.2/0.2 GB (ext4)
[12:39:50] * /fsg  0.0/0.0 GB (ext4)
[12:39:50] * /firmware  0.0/0.0 GB (ext4)
[12:39:50] * /persist  0.0/0.0 GB (ext4)
[12:39:50] * /mnt/runtime/default/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:39:50] * /storage/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:39:50] * /mnt/runtime/read/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:39:50] * /mnt/runtime/write/emulated  4.5/11.8 GB (sdcardfs)
[12:39:50] * /mnt/expand/bd43c04c-2500-40bd-9325-1de5ae577eb6  14.2/14.8 GB (f2fs)
[12:39:50] Available partitions: 
[12:39:50]  ...no available partitions
[12:39:50] <<< status
```

> Is it possible to do what I'm trying? Use half the SD as Adoptable Storage and
>   the rest as ext4 to install Kali Linux? Am I forgetting to set
>   something up?

Answer (score 1):

Here how I'get 16gb on Linux deploy hope this help somebody:

1. Use twrp, advanced, make partition ext4 swap 0 (https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-install-twrp/)
2. Use the Linux deploy terminal, configuration, check telnet, port, local host and http
3. Go to configuration again and select terminal, on terminal, put the command, `ls /dev/block`
4. Identify your ext4 partition, in my case `/dev/block/mmcblk0p2`
5. In Linux deploy, propierties, select your os and proper settings, in instalation type use partition, instalation rute use the One on the point 4, file system ext4, The other settings at your decide
6. Install
7. enjoy[image]