# Samsung J3 2016 SM-J320F Setting External SD card as Internal

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-j3

I'm new to smartphones and this is my first phone . I'm trying to sent external SD card as internal storage. Issue is that phone has only 8GB of ROM and by default 3.2 is System and 3.5 is Used space. So there is just a tiny space left on the internal memory. Android version is 5.1.1. I have rooted it with TWRP 3.0.2-0 and SuperSU. SD card is Kingstone SDca3/32GBn0557-004A00LF.

I have been reading a lot of tuturials to make external memory internal with no luck. I have tried adb tools, formating it with Mini Tool Partition Wizard-DroidThunder, a2sd, Link2SD, etc... I'm also OK with installing custom ROMs that will enable me to make internal memory of my SD card.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks xD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to adopt SD card as internal storage on Samsung devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/how-to-adopt-sd-card-as-internal-storage-on-samsung-devices)

Comment: This is for 6.0.1 Marshmallow on Galaxy S5

Comment: Since you said you're open to flashing custom ROMs in order to enable such feature, @GokulNC's reply makes sense.

Comment: Any explenation how?