# Adopting SD card for Samsung S5 mini duos G800-H

Tags: adoptable-storage, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

Has anyone managed to adopt the SD card for S5 mini duos. I've rooted it and tried to install ASPlugin (from RE) but it doesn't install either with CWR or TWPR. Also tried to partition the SD card (Samsung 64G) but the phone sees it as corrupted.

Model: SM-G800H
Android: 6.0.1
Build: MMB29M.G800HXXU1CPK1

Also I have tried all the steps here [How to adopt SD card as internal storage on Samsung devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/how-to-adopt-sd-card-as-internal-storage-on-samsung-devices)

But no success so the question is has anyone managed to get it working specifically for S5 mini duos, is there something more restrictive about this version? The post above does mention in a comment that someone might have got it working for S5 (mini duos?). Would be wonderful to know how, what exact steps.

This is after rooting the phone. Did they manage to get ASPlugin to work if so how exactly.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Android version?

Comment: Yes its Marshmallow 6.0.1

Comment: I have edited the question - specifically - for the S5 duos mini for which the steps in the posts do not work. Thanks for any help or pointers

Comment: Method in answer, marked with (NO ROOT) works not only for Samsung phones but for all phones that support adoptable storage

Comment: Hi yes that was my first try using adb, it accepts the partition command but doesn't work nothing happens to the card.

Comment: Would you explain step by step what did you exactly done?

Comment: Sure by the way really appreciate your help. Spasibo.

Comment: adb shell. Then sm list-disks which shows disk:179,64.  Then sm partition disk:179,64 private. I also tried with doing sm set-force-adoptable true first.

Comment: Mount gives the following `/dev/block/vold/public:179,65 /mnt/media_rw/8670-1CE8 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/public:179,65 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0`

Comment: Interesting here the disk is 179,65

Comment: Then try typing "sm partition disk:179,65 private" in ADB shell. Just to make clear it returns you 'disk:179,64' when you use 'sm list-disks'?

Comment: Hi yes tried both. but the storage doesn't show the options to migrate or anything just format or unmount. And yes it returns disk:179,64. I wonder if there is something strange about the S5 - if they've manage to block it somehow.

Comment: That option should be under SD card in three-dot menu. If none of this actually works than there is something off there. They shouldn't be able to block it since it's android feature.

Comment: Yup - no three dots - something strange with this. Thanks for your help

Comment: No 3 dots? Well they should be even if it's not adoptable storage.. Try press and hold recents button or menu button, idk which one is on S5..

Comment: Yes bad not menu options.