# My Smartphone doesn't allow moving my apps to the external SDcard

Tags: external-sd, android-10

So, my smartphone aren't allowing me to move the apps installed to the external SDcard (32GB).

Follow a list with the things which I've already did:

1. I've upgrade the Android system for your *lastest version*.
2. I also already formated my external SDcard. Regarding with that one, it's reading/writing files and folders *absolutely normal*.
3. I've already enabled the option *"Force allow apps on external"* on the *"Developer options"* section.
4. I also tried to move other apps beyond *Telegram*. For example: *VLC and some games*.

> **Smartphone Model: [Samsung Galaxy A01](https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/phones/galaxy-a/galaxy-a01-verizon-sm-a015vzkavzw/)**
>
> **Android Version: 10**

[image]
[image]

Comment: 2. formatted as [\[adoptable-storage\]](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)?

Comment: There aren't that option. There are only the "Format" option

Comment: unfortunately, some vendors decided to disable that feature in gui (performance reasons?) but you still can try to format your MicroSD Card as adoptable-storage from adb shell command line

Comment: [How to adopt SD card as internal storage on Samsung devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/146513)

Comment: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214233)