# Does Storage manager (SM) package manager (PM) command works in android 10,11

Tags: applications, adoptable-storage, application-manager

**Question Does Storage manager (SM) Package manager (PM) command works in android 10,11?**

I want to purchase new android mobile as new smart  phone  come.with android 9,10,11.

As I want adaptable storage as all experts told no new  mobile vendor manufacturer supports adoptable except android 6.0 marshemellow it was introduced but many forums it said that android 9.0 (https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable)  and above support but it's hidden disabled by vendor manufacturer and can be enabled through following commands

```
adb shell
sm has-adoptable 
sm set -force- adoptable true 
sm set-virtual-disk true
Reboot
```

Or

```
Adb shell
sm list-disks 
sm partition disk:179:160 mixed 25
sm format private:179,3
sm mount private:179,3
Reboot
```

Or

```
Adb shell 
pm set-install-location 2
pm get-install-location
Reboot
```

Now I want to ask that do  **Storage manager (SM) or Package manager (PM) java command** is Available in android 9,10,11 new any model smartphone mobile phone (samsung, vivo, Oppo, MI..any company any model u know ) without rooting  (as rooting may cause warranty void) will SM or PM above commands can be runned by terminal emulator and will any of the above  SM command partition or format external sd card as internal  can be enable or partly run adopt the external micro sd card through this method

If any one used any of the following mobiles the samsung galaxy 5g series   (f62, f52, m32,m42) or samsung galaxy 4g series (f41 f22 m31 m21  m12) or xiomi ( redmi 10 prime, power 9 , note 10t, mi 10i,  mi 11x) or Realme (nazo 30 ,x7, a 22, 8s, gt master edition, z7 , ) or  oppo ( a53s, a 74, f19 pro+)  vivo ( v20 v21 v21e) ,  poco (m3 pro  m3, z3,x 3)

As the following link says samsung galaxy   Galaxy A5, J5, J7, On5, S7,S9  work with these option

[How to adopt SD card as internal storage on Samsung devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/how-to-adopt-sd-card-as-internal-storage-on-samsung-devices)

Comment: What android 11 device model?

Comment: @alecxs .bro ..any model any company u know which have encoprated am PM command which can work with adoptable...I was prefring for sumaung galxy m32 or f42  but if it don't have or oppo or vivo or mi or any any company model have if it's in ur knowledge  kindly tell me as I can purchase in festival offers in discount..I can go for old  android 8,9 models to of samsung S7  as in link https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/how-to-adopt-sd-card-as-internal-storage-on-samsung-devices

Comment: It seems you found solution yourself for some older question: Root Essentials claims to install adoptable-storage (framework/sm.jar) on any android device

Comment: @Androidquery I think you would get more response if you would ask such a question in the device specific forum at https://forum.xda-developers.com. BTW: Please don't call me "bro".

Comment: @robert buddy thanx for best advice can I call u buddy friend dost  if it don't mind...bro. haha..thanx for suggestion..xda have developers and they are good for programers not novice.....still tey if some.onw answer the same

Comment: @alecxs bro "It seems you found solution yourself for some older question: Root Essentials claims to install adoptable-storage (framework/sm.jar) on any android device" yes rhia installation can be done do it work in android 9 or 10 or 11 through twrp recovery (fastboot boot  recovery.img) ..do I need rooting as roooting may void  warranty

Comment: @alecxs bro that question was different it was for adoptable storage  and it's for SM storage manager command and  PM pacakage manager. Commands...that question is not answered it commented it's just commented for closure or edit by Andrew T

Comment: It's exact the same question, only different wording, and you have already been told that no one can answer that